# sed how I can replace csv only IF line contain string?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a csv like this

```
titlemmmm;fff;ggg
mmmm;fff;ggg
mmmm;fff;ggg
```

I need to replace for obtain this

```
titlemmmm*fff*ggg
mmmm;fff;ggg
mmmm;fff;ggg
```

how I could do this

Please help me

Comment: sorry I solved my problem now whit other solution sorry for ask this

Comment: hi my solution is different to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed '/title/s/;/*/g' file.txt
```

Or if you only want to match "title" at the beginning of a line:

```
sed '/^title/s/;/*/g' file.txt
```

If you want to edit the file in place, without needing to direct the output to a new file, you can use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i '/^title/s/;/*/g' file.txt
```